# Order of automorphism group of cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, automorphism-group

Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $m$. What is the order of $\text{Aut}(G)$?

I want to know the proof as well (elementary if possible). I would still accept the proof if one answers with $m = p$, a prime. Or on top of that, I would accept the answer with extra assumption: $q \equiv 1$ mod $p$ with another prime $p$.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Since an automorphism of $G$ should map a generator of $G$ to a generator of $G$ it's enough to know how many generators does $G$ have.

If $G=\{e,g,g^2,...,g^{m-1}\}$ then a $g^i$ generates G if and only if $\operatorname{gcd}(i,m)=1$.

$\lvert \operatorname{Aut}(G)\rvert=\phi(m)$ where $\phi(m)$ is Euler's function.

For a more detailed proof:

1. Let $G=\langle g\rangle$ and $f\in\operatorname{Aut}(G)$.
2. Then $f(g)=g^i$ for some $i$. If $f$ is an isomorphism  $\langle g^i\rangle =G$ and this happens only if $\operatorname{gcd}(i,m)=1$.
3. On the other hand every homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow G$ with $f(g)=g^i$ is an isomorphism when $\operatorname{gcd}(i,m)=1$, so $\lvert \operatorname{Aut}(G)\rvert=\phi(m)$.

Comment: In fact, the automorphism group is isomorphic with the multiplicative group of integers modulo $m$ (by a very similar argument).

Comment: I totally agree tomasz.

Comment: Thanks  for editing tomasz , it looks much nicer now.

Comment: Sometimes   thinking in Greek and writing in English  doesn’t produce a nice outcome lol :)

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Comment: How would you fill in the details of the third part of your proof? Why is it that if $f:G \to G$ with $f(g) = g^i$ is an isomorphism when $gcd(i,m)=1$?

Comment: @objectivesea Since $gcd(i,m)=1$ there exist $x_1,x_2$ such that $ix_1+mx_2=1$. It's easy to prove that s is an epimorphism if you see that $g^{ix_1+mx_2}=g\rightarrow g^{i x_1}=g$ since $g^{mx_2}=1$. To prove that it's a monomorphism suppose $g^{im_1}=g^{im_2}$ then $g^{i(m_1-m_2)}=g$ and $m|i(m_1-m_2)$. Since $gcd(m,i)=1\rightarrow m|m_1-m_2\rightarrow m_1=m_2+km$. $g^{im_1}=g^{im_2+ikm}=g^{im_2}$. That's it more or less.

Answer (score 18):

**Hint:**

For a given cyclic group $G,\;\text{with}\;\; |G| = m$:
$$\text{Aut}\,(G) \cong \mathbb{Z}_m^*\tag{$\;^*:\;\;$multiplicative group}$$

Hence $\text|{Aut}\,(G)| = |\mathbb{Z}_m^*|.$

Since an automorphism of $G$ should map a generator of $G$ to a generator of $G$, it's enough to know how many generators $G$ must have.

So $|\text{Aut}(G)|=|\mathbb{Z}_m^*| = \phi(m)$ where $\phi(m)$ is [**Euler's totient function.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)

---

(Note: you do not need that $m = p$, a prime; it suffices to know that $G$ is cyclic and finite.)