# What elements does it contain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I want to show that $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ is an abelian group of order $\phi (n)$.

The automorphism group of the group $\mathbb{Z}_n$, $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$, is the group of isomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

How do the elements of $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ look like?

Comment: Multiplication by an invertible element of the ring $Z_n$.

Comment: Generalize what we talked about in your other question: how many elements of order $\;n\;$ are there in $\;\Bbb Z_n\;?$ . Exactly $\;\phi(n)\;$ , and since automorphisms map generators to generators...

Comment: Also answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267880/order-of-automorphism-group-of-cyclic-group).

Comment: There are $\phi(n)$ generators for $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$.  A map from $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is determined completely by where $\overline 1$ goes since $h(\overline m)=mh(\overline 1)$.  Now $\overline 1$ can be mapped to any element and extended to a homomorphism.  In order for the map to be surjective it has to map $\overline 1$ to a generator.  And since there are $\phi(n)$ generators there are $\phi(n)$ elements  in Aut$(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: How do we know that there are $\phi (n)$ elements in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ that have order $n$ ? @Joanpemo

Comment: @MaryStar Because we already (should) know that an element  $\;x\in\Bbb Z_n\;$ has order $\;n\;$ iff $\;g.c.d.(x,n)=1\;$ , and there are exactly $\;\phi(n)\;$ elements of this kind.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\phi\in\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ and suppose $\phi([1])=[m]$. Then, for $0\leq r<n$ we have
\begin{align*}
\phi([r])=&\phi([\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_r])\\
&=\phi(\underbrace{[1]+\cdots+[1]}_r)\\
&=\underbrace{\phi([1])+\cdots+\phi([1])}_r=\underbrace{[m]+\cdots+[m]}_r=[mr]
\end{align*}
Hence, $\phi$ is multiplication by $m$ and we may write $\phi=\phi_m$. But, $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ is closed under inverses and we have $\phi_m^{-1}=\phi_k$ for some $k$. Now,
$$
[1]=\phi_m^{-1}\phi_m([1])=\phi_k\phi_m([1])=\phi_k([m])=[mk]=[m][k]
$$
Hence, $[k]=[m]^{-1}$ and $[m]\in\mathbb{Z}_n^{\times}$.

Now, a computation similar to the one above also shows that $\phi_r\phi_s=\phi_{rs}$. Hence, the map
$$\Phi:\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)\to\mathbb{Z}_n^{\times}$$
given by $\Phi(\phi_m)=[m]$ is a homomorphism. It is now straighforward to check that this map is bijective. Hence, $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ is an abelian group of order $|\mathbb{Z}_n^\times|=\varphi(n)$.

Comment: What do the brackets mean at $\phi([1])=[m]$ ? Knowing that $\Phi (\phi_m)=[m]$ is a homomorphism and bijective, how do we conclude that $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ is an abelian group of order $|\mathbb{Z}_n^\times|=\varphi(n)$ ?

Comment: I am using the notation $[x]$ for the congruence class of $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$. You may also have seen $\overline{x}=[x]$. For your second question, you have an isomorphism $$\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)\to\mathbb{Z}_n^\times=\{[x]\in\mathbb{Z}_n\mid \gcd(x,n)=1\}$$ Since $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ is an abelian group, so is $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$. Also, the two groups have the same size. . .

Comment: Could you explain to me why we take the function $\Phi (\phi_m)=[m]$ ? Why do we take as input the multiplication of $m$ ?

Comment: Because it gives the desired isomorphism. I think you should work out all the details.