# Find $Aut(Z_{6})$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups, automorphism-group

> Question: Find $Aut\left ( \mathbb{Z}_{6} \right )$

Note that $\mathbb{Z}_{6}=\left \{ 0,1,2,3,4,5 \right \}$

Observe:

$\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}_{6}$, $k^{6}=e \equiv 0(mod6)$

Recall: Suppose $\phi$ is an isomorphism from a group G to G. Then $\forall a \in G,  \left |\phi \left ( a \right ) \right |=\left | a \right |$

But $\alpha$ is an isomorphism so is by definition also a Homomorphism.
So, $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}_{6}
\left ( k \right )\alpha=\left ( 1+\cdot \cdot \cdot +1\right )\alpha=\left ( 1 \right )\alpha+\cdot \cdot \cdot +\left ( 1 \right )\alpha=k\left ( 1 \right )\alpha$

Recall: $Aut\left ( \mathbb{Z}_{n} \right )\cong U\left ( n \right )$

So, $Aut\left ( \mathbb{Z}_{6} \right )\cong U(6)=\left \{ 1,5 \right \}$

Thus, we deduce the possible candidates to be $\left ( 1 \right )\alpha=1$ or $\left ( 1 \right )\alpha=5$

Here is where I am unable to progress further. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean $Aut(\Bbb{Z}_n) \cong U(n)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach starts off in the right direction, but then suddenly

> Recall $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb{Z}_n)\cong U(n)$
>
> So $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb{Z}_6)\cong U(6)=\{1,5\}$

Then what's left to prove? And why bother with the rest of your argument?

Comment: My mind wasn't thinking well while working on these problems on board a plane. 
The real question that has been bothering me is this:
$\alpha$ is an isomorphism from a group to itself. It is thus self-implied that $\alpha$ is a bijection and so each element is the image of a distinct element in the domain. In this sense, how is it possible for $(1)\alpha=1$ and $(1)\alpha=5$? For if this were true then the bijection map would be false.

Comment: You've shown that there are two automorphisms of $\Bbb{Z}_6$, determined by mapping $1\in\Bbb{Z}_6$ to either $1$ or $5$.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, it is enough to show that $Aut(C_6)$ has $\phi(6)=2$ elements. This was proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267880/order-of-automorphism-group-of-cyclic-group), for example. Then we have
$$
Aut(C_6)\simeq C_2.
$$
Furthermore it was shown at the [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267880/order-of-automorphism-group-of-cyclic-group), that 
$$
Aut(C_n)\simeq U(n)=(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\ast}.
$$